# Extract aggregratelist value where conditions are met

Tags: apex, map, list, aggregate

I need some continued help with this project. I have my aggregrateResult list with the needed data for every account.

How do I pull the data just for the current account?

```
global class BCI_Account_State_Count_Rollup implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

        /*
Created by MM - 1/25/2016
Purpose - count the state field for each employee on an account and update 
the corresponding state field on the account page. 
*/

        //Create List of active accounts
        list<account> myAccounts = new list<account>();
        myAccounts = [Select ID, Name from Account WHERE Type = 'Client'];
        //Create list of State, Count for State, and Account ID for all Client Accounts
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT COUNT(ID) ct, State__c st, Account__c acct FROM Employees__c WHERE Account__r.Type = 'Client' GROUP BY Account__c,State__c];

        for ( Account a : myAccounts ){
            //Start Loop


            //Map each state from the extracted aggregrateResult data to the corrisponding field on the Account page. 
        //Need something like this
        //Kansas
        a.KS__c = groupedResults.get('ct' where Account__c = a.Id and State__c = 'KS')

            //Put updated field values into a master list that will be used to bulkify the update command at the end. 


            //Loop
        }
        //End Loop
    }
}
```

Comment: The line "        a.KS__c = groupedResults.get('ct' where Account__c = a.Id and State__c = 'KS')      "  doesn't work by the way. I just typed it to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your aggregates something like the following. Your OP is somewhat unclear on what you are looking for so perhaps as you add more detail I can tailor my answer to the updated ask.

```
public static Map<String, List<AggregateResult>> groupByAccount
    (List<AggregateResult> aggregates)
{
    Map<Id, List<AggregateResult>> byAccount = new Map<String, List<AggregateResult>>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : aggregates)
    {
        Id accountId = (Id)aggregate.get('account');
        if (!byAccount.containsKey(accountId))
            byAccount.put(accountId, new List<AggregateResult>();
        byAccount.get(accountId).add(aggregate);
    }
}
```

With this data structure you can then get relevant aggregates from within your loop. You could apply a similar logic to group by state.

```
Map<String, SObjectField> stateToField = new Map<String, SObjectField>
{
    'KS' => Account.KS__c
    // , other mappings
    // use a map for scalability
}
for (Account account : accounts)
{
    List<AggregateResult> aggregates = byAccount.get(account.Id);
    Map<String, AggregateResult> byState = new Map<String, AggregateResult>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : aggregates)
    {
        SObjectField field = stateToField.get((String)aggregate.get('state'));
        if (field != null) account.put(field, (Decimal)aggregate.get('count'));
    }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to take the aggregrate count for each State from the employee object and put that number into a matching field on the Account object.  So say we have 2000 employees in Kansas. I want to put that value into a field on account called KS__c.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the code @Adrian Larson. It is going to take me a bit of time to understand what you sent me.